# mysql reverse int value using generate column

Tags: mysql

How to reverse the value of generate colum in mysql 5.7 ? For exampe, if the source column's value is -1, the generate column value is 1, if the source column's value is 1, the generate column value is -1, what should I do to archive this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html - feel free to write it up as an answer for everyone.

Comment: Reverse is string operation, reverse for `-1` is `1-`. Maybe you need in sign reverse?

Comment: It's called "negate".  Simply using the `-` in front of the real column should suffice.